# Inno Setup: CreateInputQueryPage isn't returning any value

Tags: inno-setup

Here is the script I'm using on Inno Setup. It is my first script, please understand if I'm asking something obvious.

It seems that the variable `ServerAddress` never has a value, even if I fill the input field. It looks like `Page.Values[0]` always returns an empty result. What is wrong with my code?

As you can see, I have made a test with a `testvar` variable to exclude it was a matter of variable scope, but it's not the case.

```pascal
[Code]

var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  ServerAddress: String;
  testvar: String;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'Server Informations', '',
    'Please specify the IP address, then click Next.');

  { Add items (False means it's not a password edit) }
  Page.Add('IP Address:', False);
  ServerAddress := Page.Values[0];
  testvar := 'testvalue';
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall  then begin
    MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{app} '+testvar+' : '+ServerAddress),mbInformation,MB_OK);
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\config.txt', 'test'+ServerAddress, True);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`InitializeWizard` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard) is called (and finishes) before the wizard window is even shown.

So a value (that the user will enter in the future) can hardly be known at that point. You have to read the value only after the custom page is shown. Like in your [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ServerAddress: string;  
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    { This is the right time to read the value }
    ServerAddress := Page.Values[0];

    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\config.txt', ServerAddress, True);
  end;
end;
```